# Spatio"temporal" Processing to extract Peak Positions in Data

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-network, image-recognition

I am working on an experimental setup that produces 2D widefield image data for each frequency in a frequency sweep. The resulting data has the Form MxNxFxC with M and N being the image pixels, F being the frequency steps and finally C being a fluorescence value of the pixel (m, n) at the frequency f.

The information of interest is encoded in the frequency values of a total of 8 fluorescence dips. This is an example of three arbitrary pixels:
[image]

The exact position of the dips varies slightly, as the underlying metric changes from pixel to pixel.

I usually exctract the position of these dips by fitting a model to the curve. But for a large amount of pixels (1024x1024 image size) this takes quite a toll on my measurement time.

Now to my question:

Is it feasible to train a CNN to return a data set made up of the frequency values for each dip for each pixel or is this a problem that poses no significant increase in processing over just fitting the data?

I used to convolve a basic version of the model dip with single frequency sweeps before to exctract the rough position of the dips, I assume the CNN performs something similar - at least in the first layer. What architecture for the CNN would be a good starting point to accomplish this task? Does it pose a computational advantage over "rough estimation" by just manually convolving the data traces?

Comment: Maybe you could define a parametric curve with 8 dips (e.g. a polynomial or a Bezier curve) and do some curve-to-image fitting (e.g. [this](https://raphlinus.github.io/curves/2021/03/11/bezier-fitting.html), [this](https://ijnao.um.ac.ir/article_24919_9725b0cafdf1b7d8bf117c90704ee454.pdf) or [this](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/601750/601750.pdf))